# Jquery DataTable array object into column

Tags: jquery, datatable

Good day, I am trying to figure out how could this be possible to split this array data into each column.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
      <th>column5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value1,value2,value3,value4,value5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the original output was [actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPZ5.png)

im running it via jquery datatable. any idea on how to achieve to put the data "1" and "N/A" to each column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any Javascript that supposed to go with this?

Comment: so far, this is my code {data: 'results',render: function (data) {return data;} and this is the output of the API: results: (33) ["1", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<td>value1,value2,value3,value4,value5</td>
```

with

```
<td>value1</td>
<td>value2</td>
<td>value3</td>
<td>value4</td>
<td>value5</td>
```

I don't think it's a jQuery problem, just for HTML table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am using jquery DataTable and I am new to this plugin.
data: @json($results),
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                ],
                info: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                destroy: true, 
                /*paging: false,*/
                pageLength: 20,
                columns: [
                    {data: 'results',render: function (data) {return data;}
                    }                  
                ]